# Why is constant variable value changing?

Tags: solidity, yul

I wrote a simple contract in solidity.Constant variable's value can be changed in Yul (assembly). But how and why is it changing?.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract changeConstant {
    uint256 private constant v = 5;
    function increment() public {
        assembly{   
            sstore(v, add(sload(v), 1))
        }
    }
    function getValue() public view returns(uint256 result){
        assembly {
            result := sload(v)
        }
    }
}
```

[docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables) explains:

> For a constant variable, the expression assigned to it is copied to all the places where it is accessed and also re-evaluated each time

Comment: [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables) explains:
"The compiler does not reserve a storage slot for these variables, and every occurrence is replaced by the respective value."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't change the constant, but you write to the storage slot `v = 5` and read from it.

As can be read in the [Assembly Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/assembly.html), the `sstore` command takes the arguments p and v, where p is the pointer to the storage location and v is the value to be stored.

```
sstore(p, v) -> storage[p] := v
sload(p) -> storage[p]
```

This can be confirmed by making some small changes to your code:

```
//SPDX license identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract ChangeConstant {

uint256 public constant v = 5;

uint256 public emptySlot0;
uint256 public emptySlot1;
uint256 public emptySlot2;
uint256 public emptySlot3;
uint256 public emptySlot4;

uint256 public writtenSlot;

    function increment() public {
        assembly{
            sstore(v, add(sload(v), 1))
        }
    }
    function getValue() public view returns(uint256 result){
        assembly {
            result := sload(v)
        }
    }

}
```

When writing code in solidity each state variable is stored in a slot decided by the [storage layout rules](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html?highlight=layout%20in%20storage#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage). That is why I had to define `emptySlot0-emptySlot4`. Inline assembly allows you to choose whatever slot you want to write to or read from.

Comment: >You don't change the constant, but you write to the storage slot ```v = 5``` and read from it.
When i read 1st time using ```getValue()```, it returns ```0```. if I'm reading from storage slot of ```v``` then why it returns 0 for 1st call?

Comment: And 
"For a constant variable, the expression assigned to it is copied to all the places where it is accessed and also re-evaluated each time"
means that no storage slot is created for constant variables, it's value is simply copied to all places it is accessed. So this means ```sload(v)``` is creating a new storage slot, which is initialized with ```0``` and then read/write is done at that storage slot??

Comment: An storage slot that is empty has the value zero. The storage slot at v is only filled once `increment` is called.

Comment: I've initialized ```v``` with ```5```. Why does it give ```0``` instead of ```5```.

Comment: @Abdullah0123 `v` and the storage slot are different. `v` is indeed `5`. `v` is the slot to storage: if you think of storage as an array, then `v` is an index to the array. Now in reality whenever the Solidity compiler sees `v` it replaces it with `5`: that's what your second comment means. So `sload(v)` is compiled as `sload(5)`. (Solidity's `constant` is like macros in the C language.)

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables) 
"The compiler does not reserve a storage slot for these variables, and every occurrence is replaced by the respective value."

If there's no storage slot being used for constants (according to docs), then how can you say
"you write to the storage slot ```v = 5``` and read from it."

Comment: So, this means ```sload(v)``` will be converted to ```sload(5)``` by solidity compiler, Then  read / write is done at ```5th``` index of storage array...  Am i right??

Comment: yes, you just read/write to the `5th` storage slot.